# How to Propagate JSESSIONID present in Cookie Value of each Request in Web Performance Test throughout web test?

Tags: load-testing, business-objects

I have recorded a SAP BO Application test case to just view some report using FIDDLER2 and converted into a Web Performance Test. When I am running web test it shows me some null pointer exception. After searching I came to know that we need to pass JSESSIONID in all requests throughout web test.

JSESSIONID is present in Cookie Value of each request and not response.

My Question is how do I propagate this JsessionID throughout my web test?

Even if I extract text from very first request which how do I propagate it i.e. using Querystring or form post parameter etc.